# how do i get title from foreignkey of Item

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get the title from Item Models when i added the product to wishlist.

```
class Item(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Wishlist(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'Wishlist'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Wishlists'

def __str__(self):
    return self.item.title

@login_required
def wishlist(request):
wishlist = Wishlist.objects.all()

context = {
    'wishlist': wishlist,
}
return render(request,'wishlist.html', context)
```

I tried this on Template but not working.

```
{% for object in wishlist.item.all %}
 <h1>{{ object.item.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `wishlist` is a collection of `Wishlists`, you should iterate over this like:

```
{% for object in wishlist %}
 <h1>{{ object.item.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

That being said, it might make more sense to define a many-to-many relation between an `Item` and a `Wishlist`.

Comment: i changed Foreignkey to ManyToMany relation, when i add a product to wishlist i get this. "Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use item.set() instead." How do i solve this?

Comment: @Hi3e: like the error says, you save the `Wishlist`, and then use `Wishlist.item.add(my_item)`. I suggest however that you first take a look at the documentation, to see if it fits your needs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: def add_to_wishlist(request,slug):
   item = get_object_or_404(Item,slug=slug)
   wished_item,created = Wishlist.objects.get_or_create(
    item=item,
    user = request.user,
   )
   wished_item.item.add(wished_item)
   wished_item.save()
   messages.info(request,'The item was added to your wishlist')
   return redirect("shop:wishlist")

This shows "Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use item.set() instead."

Comment: Remove the `item=item` from the `get_or_create(..)`, and replace `wished_item.item.add(wished_item)` with `wished_item.item.add(item)`.

Comment: You are correct! but another problem with the template. This does not work. 
{% for object in wishlist %}
 <h1>{{ object.item.title }}</h1>
 {% endfor %}

Comment: @Hi3e: if a list can contain multiple items, you thus will need to iterate, like `{% for object in wishlist %}{% for item in object.item.all %} <h1> {{ item.title }}</h1> {% endfor %} {% endfor %}`.

Comment: you are a genius. Thanks!